# Do you need to call willChangeValueForKey: and didChangeValueForKey:?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing

I thought home-cooked @property setters were supposed to look like this:

```
-(void) setFoo:(Foo *)newFoo {

  // Safeguards 
  // ...

  [self willChangeValueForKey:@"foo"];
  // Switcheroo
  // ...
  [self didChangeValueForKey:@"foo"];
}
```

But I see a lot of code in blog posts by people who've been doing Cocoa a lot longer than I have, where it's like this:

```
-(void) setFoo(Foo *)newFoo {

  // Safeguards 
  // ...

  // Switcheroo
  // ...
}
```

So my question is, do we need to call the KVO-notification methods? Or is it being done magically when you update the private iVar, if you're using the modern runtime?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's done magically unless you opt-out. read [this section](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-BAJEAIEE) of the KVO guide.  Note that KVC/KVO existed from time immemorial (i.e. before the introduction of `@property`) so it doesn't matter whether the setter is `@synthesize`d or not. It's not even related to the old/new runtime dichotomy.

The detail of this magic (isa-swizzling) was detailed in a [blog post](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-01-23.html) by Mike Ash. It's magic. Basically, when a key is observed, the runtime automagically replaces the implementation of the setter so that it calls the KVO notification.

Comment: The KVO guide link is broken((