# Setting MKAnnotation coordinates in real time

Tags: cocoa-touch, mkannotation

I have a Map Point object which conforms to MKAnnotation Protocol. It works as expected until I try to change its coordinates in real time.

In the beginning I tried to use :

```
[map_point setCoordinate : new_coordinate];
```

It did not work because the property is "read-only".  Apple documentation says I should add a custom "setCoordinate" and it needs to be KVO compliant.

Have read documentation about KVO.  Wish somebody could give a basic example on how to make setCoordinate KVO compliant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply implementing a `setCoordinate:` method with that exact format will automatically comply with KVO/KVC.  You don't need to do anything extra:

```
- (void)setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate
{
    //In this example, the ivar in this class that holds the coordinate
    //is named "coord".  Simply assign the new value to it...
    coord = newCoordinate;
}
```

With the method named exactly like that (you can change the parameter name `newCoordinate` though), KVO notifications will automatically be issued for you.

See [Do you need to call willChangeValueForKey: and didChangeValueForKey:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261139/do-you-need-to-call-willchangevalueforkey-and-didchangevalueforkey) for details on this.

However, if you need to change the `coordinate` in a non-compliant method, you could generate the KVO notifications manually:

```
- (void)someNonCompliantMethod
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"coordinate"];
    coord = someNewCoordinate;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"coordinate"];
}
```

Note that you can entirely avoid implementing a `setCoordiante:` method (and ivar) manually simply by declaring the `coordinate` property as `assign` or `readwrite` instead of `readonly`:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
//and @synthesize in the @implementation
```

Now, you don't need to write a custom getter or setter and will be able to directly assign to `coordinate` from the code that instantiates this class:

```
[map_point setCoordinate : new_coordinate];
```

or:

```
map_point.coordinate = new_coordinate;
```

Finally, if the only properties you need for your annotation are `title`, `subtitle`, and `coordinate`, you can also avoid creating a custom class at all and use the built-in `MKPointAnnotation` class instead which implements a writeable `coordinate` property.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. It is very helpful. Just one more question; when you say "someNonCompliantMethod", does the noncompliant part refers solely to its name not being "setCoordinate" only ?

Comment: Generally yes but I've found that sometimes NSObject is still able to automatically handle the KVO depending on how the class is coded.  If you find that a property change is not being detected, you can add the notification yourself.